# count each values in 2 arrays, and if the length each arrays not same, push that values which has longer length

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, numbers, boolean

how can i push the count values in array length which greater than another length?

let say that i want to added and subtact the values in 2 arrays,

```
IF 'index' is even
  we do arr1 + arr2
  push to 'newarr'
ELSE IF 'index' is odd
  we do arr1 - arr2
  push to 'newarr'

IF the each arrays not same length
  we should push that values array to newarr
```

the example case:

```js
function countTwoarray(arr1, arr2) {
  var result = []
  for(key in arr1 && arr2){
    if(key % 2 === 0){
      result.push(arr1[key] + arr2[key])
    } else if(key % 2 === 1){
      result.push(arr1[key] - arr2[key])
    } 
      // else if(!key){
      // result.push("in")
   // }
  }
  return result
}

console.log(countTwoarray([1, 3, 2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,1000])) 
// [ 2, 1, 5, -3, 6, 1000 ]
```

you can see the last result is `NaN`
the NaN result must be `1000` because that is the value of `arr2` which the `length longer` than `arr1` length

i want the result kike this `[ 2, 1, 5, -3, 6, 1000 ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, take a classical [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) with a counter for the index, instead of a [`for ... in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), where you could iterate over more than just the wanted indices.

Then take a length variable with the minimum length of both arrays with [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and iterate the arrays by pushing either the difference or the sum by using a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)[conditional (ternary).

At the end take the rest of each of the arrays and push this values to the result set with [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) from the minimum length with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), where each item is taken as parameter.

```js
function countTwoarray(arr1, arr2) {
    var result = [],
        i,
        l = Math.min(arr1.length, arr2.length)

  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      result.push(i % 2 ? arr1[i] - arr2[i] : arr1[i] + arr2[i]);
  }
  result.push(...arr1.slice(l), ...arr2.slice(l));
  return result;
}

console.log(countTwoarray([1, 3, 2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1000]));
```

Comment: i got it , i was a little confused about the ```result.push(...arr1.slice(l), ...arr2.slice(l))`` do  @NinaScholz

Comment: it take just the rest of the arrays, in one case it should be an empty array, in the other some items.

Comment: yes i was tried to make another variable to check after slice it, but if they are empty, so if the variable empty is not mean undefined ?? if it was undefined, and push it to result arr, the value will undefined in that arr result

Comment: yess if we spread it it will not push to that . result arr, i was trying to not use spread and the result something like this `[ 2, 1, 5, -3, 6, -998, [], [ 1 ] ]` if not using spread